# Printing multiple HTML lines from JSP

Tags: html, jsp, multiline, println

```
    out.println(%><form> + 
        <p><label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" /></p>  + 
        <p><label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" /></p> +
        <p class="submit"> +
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Login" /> +
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Registrer" /> +
        </p> +
    </form> <%);
```

That is what i thought i could do, but obviously i can't so my question is, how do i print multiple lines of HTML?
Is there a better way to do it than the way i'm doing ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You've to put them in one large quoted string.

```
out.println("<form>" + 
    "<p><label for=\"username\">Username:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" /></p>"  + 
    "<p><label for=\"password\">Password:</label><input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" /></p>" +
    "<p class=\"submit\">" +
        "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" value=\"Login\" />" +
        "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" value=\"Registrer\" />" +
    "</p>" +
"</form>");
```

But much better is to just **not** use `out.println()` (and all other *scriptlets* in JSP). Put HTML plain in JSP and use if necessary [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) core tags to control the flow.

E.g.

```html
<c:if test="${empty activeuser}">
  <form>
    <p><label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" /></p>
    <p><label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" /></p>
    <p class="submit">
      <input type="submit" name="button" value="Login" />
      <input type="submit" name="button" value="Registrer" />
    </p>
  </form> 
</c:if>
```

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)
- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)